# Windows CE - Button Clicks are not firing when the a window form is displayed using form.invoke

Tags: .net, vb.net, winforms, windows-ce

Below is my problem.

I have `form A` and `form B`.
I am showing `form A` as `formA.ShowDialog()`
But I am trying to show the `formB` using `form.Invoke()`
`Form B` contains 3 buttons.

I have a class which holds the instance of `form B` and displays it. The class is a singleton in actual.

```
Class UIContainer

Dim objFrmB as FormB


private Sub New
objFrmB= new FrmB
End Sub

//GetInstance() - gets the instance

Public Sub ShowFrmB() 
 objFrmB.Invoke(New EventHandler(AddressOf InvokeForm))
End Sub

Private Sub InvokeForm(ByVal o As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs)
            If Not objFrmB Is Nothing Then
                With objFrmB
                    .Visible = True
                    .Refresh()
                End With
            Else
                Throw New Exception("UIContainer Failed to invoke the requested form.")
            End If
End Sub

End Class
```

I am calling the `ShowFrmB()` and the form is visible. But the events associated to the buttons are not firing.

The buttons are enabled and contains click events. Please help

I am working on VS 2008 and using CE 3.5 OS along with VB.Net

**UPDATE**

This was call from FrmA.

`UIContainer.GetInstance().ShowFrmB`

Comment: Can you please show how are you calling ShowFrmB?

Comment: Looks like some problem with message loop. ShowDialog has its own message loop, modeless form uses message loop from the caller thread.

Comment: @varocarbas from form A we just call ShowFrmB

Comment: Yes. I was just feeling curious about the way you are instantiating UIContainer as far as you have private Sub New; also objFrmB does not seem to be instantiated anywhere. Not sure either why you are starting FrmB as you are doing it: if you would put all the code inside InvokeForm into ShowFrmB, do Dim objFrmB as FormB = new FormB and instantiate UIContainer as usual (-> Dim thisForm As UIContainer = New UIContainer    thisForm.ShowFrmB()); everything, including the events of the buttons should work fine.

Comment: The `GetInstance()` method initializes the objFrmB and its working. But I need to use the invoke. Am I missing any steps or is there any issue with invoke.

Comment: My comment (and my knowledge) is focused on standard winforms. Not sure about the windows-ce implications. Perhaps you should highlight the embedded part much clearly to get quickly people with the right expertise. Also it is always helpful to have a fully working/easily-/immediately-reproduceable code.

Comment: Also in win forms, while using invoke, do we need to add any steps ?